# Bootstrap Responsive setting not working

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**I am trying to create a user login page that is responsive. I am doing this within Angular 5. When displaying it on a full screen, all is OK.**

[image]

**But when I reduce the size of the browser, it seems that the responsive aspect is not working**

[image]

**I have added the information below for the HTML and SCSS files. 
What am I doing wrong?
TIA**

```
$ ng -v
Angular CLI: 1.6.1
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.1.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.38
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.23
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.1
@schematics/angular: 0.1.13
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

**admin-login.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive ">
      <form (submit)="loginUser($event)">
        <div class="input" >
          <label>Username</label>
          <input class="btn-block" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input class="btn-block" type="password">
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="input"> 
          <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
      </form>
      <br/>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="forgot-password float-left" style="font-size:20px">
          Forgot Password
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="forgot-password float-right" style="font-size:20px">
          Register
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**admin-login.component.scss**

```
:host {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


div.input {
    position: relative;
}

div.input label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 10px;
    background: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 2px;
}

div.input input {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    outline: 0;
}

div.input {
    margin-top: 20px;
}


.Absolute-Center {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  }

  .Absolute-Center.is-Responsive {
    width: 50%; 
    height: 50%;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 40px;
  }
```

**UPDATE**

@WebDevBooster - thanks so much for the input! I followed the information here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ and focused on the part that spoke how one could simulate centering a form as well. Now my problem is resolved.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell from a quick glance, all of your custom css can be replaced with native Bootstrap 4 classes. And it is really recommended that you do that because introducing unnecessary css hacks tends to require even more css hacks to fix the problems caused by the original css hacks...

Comment: The whole point of Bootstrap 4 is that it allows you to get done almost everything you'll ever need without writing any custom css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because you haven't used a column. ALL content must go into a column that sits inside a row. Never into a `.row` directly.

That's because Bootstrap rows and columns are designed to work together. Never use the one without the other.

Note that the use of `.col` in the example below means that the column will be full-width no matter the screen size. To make it more responsive you need to add responsive column classes as needed.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive ">
                <form (submit)="loginUser($event)">
                    <div class="input" >
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input class="btn-block" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input class="btn-block" type="password">
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="input"> 
                        <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" value="Login">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <br/>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="forgot-password float-left" style="font-size:20px">
                        Forgot Password
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="forgot-password float-right" style="font-size:20px">
                        Register
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is also possible to put content directly into a `.container` i.e. without the use of rows and columns. However, that will not be responsive. And as soon as you use a `.row` you must use at least one `.col` inside that row. And put all your content inside that column(s).